# PostgreSQL ignores implicit casts in some situations

Tags: postgresql, cast, enum

The setup (tried only on PostgreSQL 9.6):

```
CREATE TYPE MY_ENUM AS ENUM ('a', 'b');
CREATE CAST (CHARACTER VARYING AS MY_ENUM) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE TABLE t (x MY_ENUM);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a'::MY_ENUM), ('b'::MY_ENUM);
```

These work just fine, as expected:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a');
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 'a';
```

But these don't:

```
PREPARE p(CHARACTER VARYING) AS SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = $1;
;; error: operator does not exist: my_enum = character varying

CREATE FUNCTION f(ix CHARACTER VARYING, OUT ox MY_ENUM) AS
$$
    SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = ix
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
;; error: operator does not exist: my_enum = character varying

CREATE FUNCTION f(ix CHARACTER VARYING) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM t WHERE input_type = ix;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT f('piano');
;; error: operator does not exist: my_enum = character varying
```

According [to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createcast.html):

> If the cast is marked AS `IMPLICIT` then it can be invoked implicitly in any context, whether assignment or internally in an expression.

So why the errors?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would point out that PostgreSQL has an automatic cast from text literals to any enum, so the statements that work also work _without_ the `CAST` that you created, including without the `::MY_ENUM`. Perhaps your cast is ignored because of the standard one.

Comment: When quoting the manual, it's tremendously helpful to also link to the source. And please always provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: Sure, I've added the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is this:

In the first two (working) examples, `'a'` is just an [**untyped string literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) - which is strictly different from `varchar`. The conversion to your custom `enum` type is provided by basic input/output functions of the enum type. (There is no explicit entry in the system catalog `pg_cast`.) Postgres determines the best match for a data type as the user did not provide one. **Your custom cast is not even needed**. Neither for type resolution nor for operator resolution.

In the following examples, you pass a **typed value** (`varchar`). Now, your custom cast may be of use. For example, this wouldn't work without your custom cast:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a'::varchar);
```

Your examples are not plain assignments, but expressions with the operator `=`. We are in the realm of [*Operator Type Resolution*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html). Item 2a states:

> If one argument of a binary operator invocation is of the unknown type, then assume it is the same type as the other argument for this check.

That would cover `my_enum_column = 'foo'` - with untyped literal.

But there is nothing that can be stretched to cover `my_enum_column = 'foo'::varchar`. Seems like the fact that only a generic `=` operator for left and right operand `anyenum` is available is not enough to clue in operator resolution:

```sql
-- missing operators:
SELECT oprleft::regtype, oprright::regtype, *
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprname = '='
AND   ('anyenum'::regtype IN (oprleft, oprright) OR
       'my_enum'::regtype IN (oprleft, oprright));
```

```
 oprleft | oprright | ...
 --------+----------+----
 anyenum | anyenum  | ...
(1 row)
```

You would have to register a more explicit operator for this. But I wouldn't do that. I would do things like (also note various orthogonal syntax fixes):

```sql
PREPARE p(my_enum) AS SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = $1;  -- prepare with type my_enum
EXECUTE p('a'::varchar); -- then your cast kicks in
EXECUTE p('a'); -- untyped string literal works in any case
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f1(ix my_enum, OUT ox my_enum)   -- again, declare enum
  RETURNS SETOF my_enum AS
$$
SELECT x FROM t WHERE x = ix
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT * FROM f1('a'::varchar);
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f2(ix my_enum)  -- same here
  RETURNS SETOF t AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = ix;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM f2('a'::varchar);
SELECT * FROM f2('a');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42e9dccc416bdd9f5b6d287ceb9c6f59)*

Or just add explicit casts. That's simplest and safest. The [manual warns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html) (on the same page you quoted):

> It is wise to be conservative about marking casts as implicit. ...

There is more - recommended reading.

If you must create that custom cast (or even add an operator), consider using `text` instead of `varchar`, which is the ["preferred type" among string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html#CATALOG-TYPCATEGORY-TABLE) and hence more robust against possible corner-case issues.

Comment: I used `varchar` simply because that's the type that JDBC uses for strings. Either way - what you describe makes sense but seems to contradict the documentation entry I quoted in the question. Seems like "in any context" somehow excludes operators. Do you think the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov: `varchar` is not wrong in any way. `text` is just slightly more robust here, as it takes precedence over `varchar` in some situations if both are available.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov: It's a complex matter. The manual doesn't seem incorrect to me. I added more details to my explanation. One might argue that operator resolution should be improved to work for the case. But this might create ambiguities in other contexts. (And there are simple solutions: untyped literal or explicit cast.) You might post to pgsql-general@lists.postgresql.org or even https://www.postgresql.org/account/login/?next=/account/submitbug/ and ask whether this can be improved.

Comment: I see, thank you!